# Sort entries in a category via entry field

Tags: entries, categories, sorting, group

I have a section for Businesses. I also have categories that these businesses can belong to. On each category page I want to list all the businesses that belong to that category. So far so good, but here's the rub: Each business also has an entry field that relates the business to a Town entry.

Businesses belong both to a category and a town entry.

On the category page I want to list the businesses by towns. So instead of having a laundry list of businesses, the businesses would be broken up by the different towns they belong to:

```
Town A
    - Business 1
    - Business 2
Town B
    - Business 3
Town C
    - Business 4
    - Business 5
    - Business 6
```

I am grabbing my businesses like this:

`{% set businesses = craft.entries.relatedTo(category) %}`

I have seen other answers to different questions suggest GROUP, but I'm not sure how to correctly go about using the group method on an array when I am trying to group via another array (entry field).

I tried this, but it results in "Object of class Craft\ElementCriteriaModel could not be converted to string":

`{% set businessesByTown = businesses|group('bizTown') %}`

I know that's fishy and incorrect, but I don't know how to accomplish it the right way. `bizTown` is the entry field I want to sort by.

If anyone could help, that'd be wonderful! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting this error because the "entries" fields are always considered to be a query (ElementCriteriaModel) that can return more than one element. Therefore, if you know for sure that you will always have one and only one town linked to a business, you could do something like that:

```
{% set businessesByTown = businesses|group('bizTown[0].title') %}
```

If the title field is the name of the town you should get an associative array with the town names as keys and the businesses entries as values.

*Additional info about sorting, following swthate's comment below:*

If you want to sort the businesses, I think it can be done in the original query, so it would become:

```
{% set businesses = craft.entries.relatedTo(category).order('title') %}
```

However, the towns cannot be sorted directly since Twig's sort filter uses asort which sorts the array based on values. What you can do then is extract the `businessesByTown` array's keys in another array:

```
{% set towns = businessesByTown|keys|sort %}
```

You now have a sorted list of towns. Using this list, you can loop on all towns and businesses like that:

```
{% for town in towns %}
    {{ town }}
    {% set townBusinesses = businessesByTown[town] %}
    {% for business in townBusinesses %}
        {{ business.title }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Awesome, it works great. Thanks for the clear description!

Comment: One quick follow-up, if I wanted to order both businesses and towns alphabetically, where would I put `.order('title')`?

Comment: Updated my answer following your comment.