# Best way to improve complex query?

Tags: performance, queries, eager-loading

This question is related to a previous question I asked: [Sort entries in a category via entry field](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/20860/sort-entries-in-a-category-via-entry-field)

I have a page that is running the same query from the previous question:

```
{% set businesses = craft.entries.relatedTo(category) %}
{% set state  = entry.bizTown.first.townCounty.first.countyRegion.first.regionState.first ?? 'N/A' %}
{% set businessesByTown = businesses|group('bizTown.first.townCounty.first.countyRegion.first.regionState[0].title') %}

{% if businesses|length %}
    {% for town, businessesInTown in businessesByTown %}
        <ul class="three-col-list">
            <h3>{{town}}</h3>
            <ul>
                {% for business in businessesInTown %}
                <li class="business-cat__item">
                    {% if business.ytVideoId|length %}
                        <i class="fa fa-video-camera" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    {% endif %}
                    <strong>{{ business.link }}</strong><br>

                    {% set twn = business.bizTown.first %}
                    <a class="business-cat__item--town" href="{{twn.url}}">{{twn.title}}</a>
                </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </ul>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %} ... {% endif %}
```

This is on a template which is displaying entries of a given sub-category. It separates the entires (the businesses) according to its state. It also displays what town each business belongs to.

**Unforunately this takes the page ~20 seconds to render!** I've tried looking into using plugins for custom SQL queries, and using eager loading.

I have read through [this article](https://tighten.co/blog/craft-cms-building-complex-queries-by-extending-the-elementcriteriamodel) a lot and have poked around inside their plugin, but I still don't know where/how to start! Likewise with eager loading, with all the crap I have going on in this/these queries, I'm not sure where to start with that, either.

At this point I feel like this is abstracting beyond my comfort level, and I'd love some expert input. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason to do `entry.bizTown.first.townCounty.first.countyRegion.first.regionState.[0].title` again on the third line in code example instead of doing `state.title`? 

Because now you're making craft look up the same object (accross multiple relations) twice.

Comment: Changing line 3 to `{% set businessesByTown = businesses|group(state.title) %}` results in "Impossible to access an attribute ("title") on a string variable ("N/A")."